# Find path in grid with mostly k moves and maximum score

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem: given an `N` by `M` grid of positive integers, find a maximum score you can get by traveling from the top left corner to the bottom right one. A score of a path is the sum of all the values you collect on the said path (staying on the same cell is a possible turn). Also, the length of the path must be mostly `L`. For example: let's say we have the following grid (`N = 5`, `M = 6`):

```
1  1  1  1  1  1
10 10 1  1  1  1
1  10 1  10 10 10
1  10 10 10 1  10
1  1  1  1  1  1
```

If `L = 10`, the answer should be 83. You get this by following this path:

```
1
10 10
   10 
   10 10 10 1 10
              1
```

And staying on one of the 10's for a single turn.

If `L = 11`, the answer should be 102. You get this by following the path of 10's in the original grid.

I have come up with an algorithm of complexity O(N^2*M^2*L), but this is too slow, as N and M can go up to 100 and L can go to 1000. My algorithm's basic idea is as follows: calculate the answer for each tuple `(i1, j1, i2, j2, k)`, where `(i1, j1)` is the starting cell, `(i2, j2)` is the destination cell and `k` is the path length. I start from `k = 0` and work my way up to `L`. Do you have any suggestions on how I could optimize this idea? Or even a whole new insight into the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to compute for each tuple of the form (*i*, *j*, *k*), the maximum score of a path of length exactly *k*, that starts from cell (0, 0), and ends in (*i*, *j*).  Let us denote this value as best(*i*, *j*, *k*).

By convention, if there is no path of length k starting in (0, 0) and ending in (*i*, *j*), we want to have best(*i*, *j*, *k*) = -infinity.

---

For *k* = 1, there is a single path with length 1 that starts in the top-left corner, therefore:

- best(0, 0, 1) = input_matrix(0, 0).
- best(*i*, *j*, 1) = -infinity, if (*i*, *j*) is not (0, 0).

For *k* > 1 we can compute best(*i*, *j*, *k*) using the values of best(*, *, *k* - 1):

best(*i*, *j*, *k*) = input_matrix(*i*, *j*) + max(best(*a*, *b*, *k* - 1)), where the `max` is taken over all *a*, *b*, such that the cell (*a*, *b*) is a neighbor of the cell (*i*, *j*).

---

Now, that the best matrix has been constructed, the answer to the original question can be found by computing:

max(best(*N* - 1, *M* - 1, *k*)), where the `max` is taken over all *k* between 1 and *L*.

---

The complexity of this approach is **O**(N ⋅ M ⋅ L).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's a very clever insight :)

Comment: Thanks for appreciating! :-)